# Form submit not redirecting with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app that I've deployed using Heroku.  When I run the app locally, I'm able to successfully redirect after submitting a form.  However, on Heroku, it doesn't seem to be doing the redirect.

Here are my logs from Heroku:

```
2013-05-23T03:07:34.010275+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/projects/1/steps/0" for 76.118.180.235 at 2013-05-23 03:07:34 +0000

2013-05-23T03:07:34.940208+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/projects/1/steps/update_ancestry?stepID=3&stepAncestry=1%2F2&position=2" for 76.118.180.235 at 2013-05-23 03:07:34 +0000
2013-05-23T03:07:34.975195+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/projects/1/steps/update_ancestry?stepID=1&stepAncestry=0&position=0" for 76.118.180.235 at 2013-05-23 03:07:34 +0000
2013-05-23T03:07:34.999327+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/projects/1/steps/update_ancestry?stepID=2&stepAncestry=1&position=1" for 76.118.180.235 at 2013-05-23 03:07:34 +0000
```

logs from running on a local server (removed extraneous debug messages):

```
Started PUT "/projects/86/steps/0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-22 23:08:57 -0400
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/86/steps
Completed 302 Found in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 6.9ms)

Started GET "/projects/86/steps" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-22 23:08:57 -0400

Started GET "/projects/86/steps/update_ancestry?stepID=463&stepAncestry=0&position=0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-22 23:08:57 -0400

Started GET "/projects/86/steps/update_ancestry?stepID=471&stepAncestry=463&position=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-22 23:08:57 -0400
```

You can see that in the Heroku logs, it's not doing the redirect.

What could be going wrong here?  It's doesn't seem like Heroku is giving me any error messages...

steps_controller.rb:

```
class StepsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_global_variables

  def update
    @step = @project.steps.find_by_position(params[:id])
    @step.images.each do |image|
      image.update_attributes(:saved => true)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @step.update_attributes(params[:step])
        format.html { redirect_to project_steps_path(@project), :notice => 'Step was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @step.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
  def get_global_variables
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @steps = @project.steps.order("position")
    @numSteps = @steps.count
    @ancestry = @steps.pluck(:ancestry) # array of ancestry ids for all steps
    @allBranches # variable for storing the tree structure of the process map
    @user = @project.user # user who created the project
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you changed something in the controller and forgotten to commit and push? Can you add the controller code as well?

Comment: I added my controller method above for updating a step (in my steps_controller.rb).  When I do a git status, it says I have nothing to commit.

Comment: I've updated my controller code above.

Comment: Strangest thing happened to me today, code on my local machine was behaving normally but on my staging server it was not.  Turned out to be bad logic in one of my helpers.  It could be content headers are not being assigned correctly.  In other words, its likely something wrong with the form.  I would start by tweaking the form a little, ensuring its sending the correct format on your Heroku server.  You could use logs for instance to track that.

Comment: thanks!  I went through my form and cleaned it up, and it seems to have worked!